# Can you use CartoDB.js with maps hosted on the CartoDB website

Tags: carto

Is there any way to use the cartoDB.js library with maps hosted on the CartoDB website?  From the documentation it looks like the library can only be used for maps you make on your own website -- is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't run CartoDB.js without some HTML webpage. There are a lot of tools out there for hosting a simple HTML webpage though. One I often use is a GitHub Gist. Although GitHub wont display it as rendered HTML for you on its own, you can use bl.ocks to then see the result. The key is to name it index.html. You can see a ton of my Gists over on

http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill

If you want to see how I create them, I made a little movie for you here,

[image: Imgur]